# Nonphysical results with NDSolve for two coupled nonlinear ODEs

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, nonlinear

I have a thermal problem, where I have two long strips of metal connected to each other by a dielectric along their length(sketch attached).  The lower strip has its temperature defined at each end.  The temperature of the top strip defined at the hot end only.  The problem is to determine the equilibrium temperature distributions in the two metal strips. This is a coupled system of two nonlinear differential equations.

I am having the problem of getting unexpected nonphysical results.  For instance, I have the lower conductor held at 30 K for x>0.8, but I don't see this in the solution.  The Tc around x=1 has some sharp features that are surprising.  I am not getting execution errors, but no change of options for sampling or precision makes any difference.   This is about as simple a system as you can find, but I am having trouble with it.  I had done a similar problem a couple of years ago and got help here, but this problem seems different.   I am attaching my code and a sketch of the geometry of the system.   Thanks, Harvey

[image: Geometry of thermal problem]

```
\[Kappa][t_] = 5.4*10^\[Minus]3 t;
cu20Int = \!\(\*
TagBox[
StyleBox[
RowBox[{"InterpolatingFunction", "[", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"List", "[", 
RowBox[{"List", "[", 
RowBox[{"1.0144953594884303`", ",", "314.9235745367797`"}], "]"}], 
        "]"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"List", "[", 
RowBox[{"5", ",", "7", ",", "0", ",", 
RowBox[{"List", "[", "21", "]"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"List", "[", "4", "]"}], ",", "0", ",", "0", ",", "0", ",", 
         "0", ",", "Automatic", ",", 
RowBox[{"List", "[", "]"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"List", "[", "]"}], ",", "False"}], "]"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"List", "[", 
RowBox[{"List", "[", 
RowBox[{"1.0144953594884303`", ",", "1.4453800647656718`", ",", 
          "2.282728305691647`", ",", "3.5821365454253473`", ",", 
          "5.97733185698794`", ",", "10.09286826548649`", ",", 
          "12.768890052825043`", ",", "17.52127301835548`", ",", 
          "23.44785438764171`", ",", "27.974749513478848`", ",", 
          "34.417160427276706`", ",", "40.94909507281463`", ",", 
          "47.641525915307355`", ",", "56.45372456213402`", ",", 
          "79.45044008195171`", ",", "96.35368148253369`", ",", 
          "119.90412619867278`", ",", "162.16045701509708`", ",", 
          "224.33063203230932`", ",", "298.7017541675403`", ",", 
          "314.9235745367797`"}], "]"}], "]"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"List", "[", 
RowBox[{"Developer`PackedArrayForm", ",", 
RowBox[{"List", "[", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "1", ",", "2", ",", "3", ",", "4", ",", "5", ",", 
           "6", ",", "7", ",", "8", ",", "9", ",", "10", ",", "11", 
           ",", "12", ",", "13", ",", "14", ",", "15", ",", "16", ",",
            "17", ",", "18", ",", "19", ",", "20", ",", "21"}], "]"}],
          ",", 
RowBox[{"List", "[", 
RowBox[{"24.523527600457015`", ",", "36.92464363210667`", ",", 
           "63.21110504999773`", ",", "107.28863519402005`", ",", 
           "194.13770143426433`", ",", "356.9418398143122`", ",", 
           "455.768655188985`", ",", "620.3838186441045`", ",", 
           "770.1774768772134`", ",", "841.4727934560221`", ",", 
           "856.3526122914373`", ",", "820.6452758175025`", ",", 
           "746.9412202658383`", ",", "647.347585800924`", ",", 
           "490.2647714415897`", ",", "445.9485895646173`", ",", 
           "410.95808426737415`", ",", "402.729337154694`", ",", 
           "394.4520344858614`", ",", "410.06591302304656`", ",", 
           "406.1986687062143`"}], "]"}]}], "]"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"List", "[", "Automatic", "]"}]}], "]"}],
ShowSpecialCharacters->False,
ShowStringCharacters->True,
NumberMarks->True],
FullForm]\)

manganinInt = \!\(\*
TagBox[
StyleBox[
RowBox[{"InterpolatingFunction", "[", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"List", "[", 
RowBox[{"List", "[", 
RowBox[{"0.9753607234356878`", ",", "310.145456679438`"}], "]"}], 
        "]"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"List", "[", 
RowBox[{"5", ",", "7", ",", "0", ",", 
RowBox[{"List", "[", "13", "]"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"List", "[", "4", "]"}], ",", "0", ",", "0", ",", "0", ",", 
         "0", ",", "Automatic", ",", 
RowBox[{"List", "[", "]"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"List", "[", "]"}], ",", "False"}], "]"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"List", "[", 
RowBox[{"List", "[", 
RowBox[{"0.9753607234356878`", ",", "1.0162895962687202`", ",", 
          "1.713010617168378`", ",", "2.697366416377381`", ",", 
          "5.435874150535348`", ",", "9.705279132139196`", ",", 
          "16.01831959369563`", ",", "29.341703831082857`", ",", 
          "50.3232361903219`", ",", "90.63679858293607`", ",", 
          "171.62665482620642`", ",", "285.9671762575716`", ",", 
          "310.145456679438`"}], "]"}], "]"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"List", "[", 
RowBox[{"Developer`PackedArrayForm", ",", 
RowBox[{"List", "[", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "1", ",", "2", ",", "3", ",", "4", ",", "5", ",", 
           "6", ",", "7", ",", "8", ",", "9", ",", "10", ",", "11", 
           ",", "12", ",", "13"}], "]"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"List", "[", 
RowBox[{"0.07073327688329628`", ",", "0.07772550942089118`", ",", 
           "0.15055808295036083`", ",", "0.2957620874259442`", ",", 
           "0.7283473302893886`", ",", "1.7246143638180544`", ",", 
           "3.2746434046727253`", ",", "6.6281846120297665`", ",", 
           "10.4273821641863`", ",", "13.620740835491974`", ",", 
           "16.167145238878646`", ",", "21.538162025846894`", ",", 
           "22.146360561146377`"}], "]"}]}], "]"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"List", "[", "Automatic", "]"}]}], "]"}],
ShowSpecialCharacters->False,
ShowStringCharacters->True,
NumberMarks->True],
FullForm]\)

Plot[cu20Int[t], {t, 3, 300}]
Plot[manganinInt[t], {t, 3, 300}]

LogLogPlot[{\[Kappa][t], cu20Int[t], manganinInt[t]}, {t, 3, 300}]

copperwidth = .004 25.4;
copperthickness = .018;
dielectricthickness = .011 25.4 ;
manganinwidth = 6.;
manganinthickness = 0.001 25.4;


ccConductance[t_] = cu20Int[t] copperwidth  copperthickness   10^-3;
gConductance[t_] = 
  1.5 manganinInt[t] 2 manganinwidth manganinthickness   10^-3;
dConductance[t_] = 
  4  \[Kappa][t] copperwidth /(dielectricthickness) 10^-3;



solSection1 = 
 NDSolve[{0.0033 D[ ccConductance[Tc[x]] D[Tc[x], x], x] - 
     300. 7.854545454545456`*^-6 (Tc[x]^2/2 - Tg[x]^2/2) == 0, 
   0.0033 D[gConductance[Tg[x]] D[Tg[x], x], x] + 
     300.  7.854545454545456`*^-6 (Tc[x]^2/2 - Tg[x]^2/2) == 0, 
   DirichletCondition[{Tg[x] == 300, Tc[x] == 300}, x == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[Tg[x] == 30, x >= 0.8]}, {Tc, 
   Tg}, {x} \[Element] Line[{{0}, {1}}], 
  InitialSeeding -> {Tg[x] == 60., Tc[x] == 200.}]


Plot[Tc[x ] /. solSection1[[1, 1]], {x, 0, 1}]
Plot[(Tg[x ] /. solSection1[[1, 2]]), {x, 0, 1}]

Plot[(Tg[x ] /. solSection1[[1, 2]]) - (Tc[x ] /. 
    solSection1[[1, 1]]), {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: Have you see the [HeatTransferPDEComponent](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HeatTransferPDEComponent.html) that would avoid problems in the equation setup.

Comment: How did you model the dielectric stripe?

Comment: I will check out the Heat Transfer link.

Comment: The dielectric stripe has finite thickness, so the heat flow is related to the temperature difference between Tc and Tg at each position along it length and the integral of the thermal conductivity.  The axial conduction is ignored, being much lower than the metals.  This coupling is the source of the nonlinearity.

Comment: The other source of nonlinearity is that the thermal conductances vary as a function of temperature.